# not able to install airflow initdb

Tags: airflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda2/bin/airflow", line 25, in 
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/**init**.py", line 31, in 
    from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/**init**.py", line 24, in 
    from .decorators import apply_defaults as _apply_defaults
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 34, in 
    from airflow import settings
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 36, in 
    from airflow.configuration import conf, AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG  # NOQA F401
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 44, in 
    standard_library.install_aliases()
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/future/standard_library/**init**.py", line 483, in install_aliases
    import test
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/test.py", line 9
    PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

issue with my /anaconda2/lib/python2.7/test.py file ,removed this 
now airflow working fine